# Can't drag navigation item on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I can't drag a navigation item onto my `UINavigationBar`. It only lets me drag a bar button item. Is there any way to add a back button programmatically? Thanks.

Comment: You get a back button automatically when you push a second controller onto the stack. Is that what you want, or are you trying to make a custom button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in viewDidLoad

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

and implement backAction,

```
-(void)backAction
{
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

simple do this to add button

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=barBtn;
```

for change title and attribute just use

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
```